# How do I create a link that passes an ID for a custom action in Rails?0 <%= link_to "PDF", :action => "showpdf", :id => "#{@letter.id}.pdf" %>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have the following code:

```
 <%= link_to "PDF", :action => "showpdf", :id => "#{@letter.id}.pdf" %>
```

'showpdf' is an action in my Letters controller.

My expectation is that this link should yield the following:

```
 http://domain.com/letters/showpdf/id.pdf
```

But instead, I get:

```
 http://domain.com/letters/showpdf?id.pdf
```

If the default routes are :controller/:action/:id shouldn't this work?

Do I need to do something in the routes, even though the format for default appear right?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like:

```
<%= link_to "PDF", :action => "show", :id => letter.id, :format => :pdf %>
```

where your route would be

:controller/:action/:id.:format

and in your controllers "show" action:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.pdf  .....
  format.html .....
end
```

Comment: I don't think the respond_to works...PDFKit is middleware...so not sure if that has anything to do with it...I can try again, but I did do this approach earlier,...maybe I missed something.

Comment: I still can't remove the layout -- I used this:      format.pdf  { render :layout => false}